# Finding public key for ECC

Tags: encryption, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I have the following Elliptic Curve:

y^2 = x^3 + 9x + 17 mod 23 (a = 9, b = 17, p = 23) with a base point G = (16,5)

With this information and using the private key PA = 10, how can I calculate the private key nA?
I know the equation is PA = nA * G, but I am not sure how to actually perform the calculation.

Comment: Does everything clear?

Comment: FYI, in stackoverflow, one upvotes the answer if it is useful to them. One accept the answer if the answer satisfies you as the original poster. This helps to community to see that the question has valid answer.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your title, you can use SageMath to find it.

Assuming that the private key is 10, yes it is an integer between 1 and the order of the curve `E.order()`.

The public key is then calculated as `[10]G`. Here `[10]` means add the `G` itself 10 times `G+G+G+G+G+G+G+G+G+G`. Note that this is not an ordinary addition of tuples. It is an elliptic curve point addition based on the tangent and chord rule.

```
E = EllipticCurve(GF(23),[9,17])
print(E)
print(E.order())

G = E(16,5)
print(10*G)
```

prints

```
Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + 9*x + 17 over Finite Field of size 23
32
(3 : 18 : 1)
```

Try online at [SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxzVbBVcM3JySwoyUx2Li0qS9Vwd9MwMtbUibbUMTSP1eQqKMrMK9FwhTP08otSUos0NDW5uNxBejUMzXRMYbKGBlrumgD6gBcI&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) and learn SageMath if you going to study cryptography. SageMath uses Python3 syntax, therefore easy to learn. And, here SageMath reference for [Elliptic curves over finite fields](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/arithmetic_curves/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/ell_finite_field.html) and [the tutorial of SageMath](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/introduction.html).